# Creating a Notification at a particular time through Alarm Manager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I am trying to create a notification at a particular time. Im creating a broadcast receiver and calling it through the AlarmManager. Problem is that the broadcast is not received and that I am not getting any notifications.

Registering the Broadcast Receiver in the Manifest,

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.example.android.receivers">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.android.receivers.AlarmReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is the Broadcast Receiver,

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context pContext, Intent pIntent) {

//      if (pIntent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
//          
//      }
        Log.d("Alarm Receiver", "onReceive called");        
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(pContext).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setContentTitle("Test Notification")
                        .setContentText("Test Notification made by Syed Ahmed Hussain");
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(pContext, CalendarView.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(pContext);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(CalendarView.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) pContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Code from Main Activity which creates an Alarm.

```
/**
     * 
     * @param pDate
     * @param pTime
     */
    private void createNotification(String pDate, String pTime) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
//      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
    }
```

Can anyone please point out and rectify what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: didn't my answer helped you?

Answer (score 8):

You have a wrong definition of the Receiver in your Manifest.

Try this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.android.receivers.AlarmReceiver" />
```

in `android:name` you have to specify the absolute package+class of the receiver, or the relative from the `package="com.example.android"` you specified in the root element of the Manifest. e.g:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android" >
```

---

Action sections of receivers are to specify which actions to listen. So you can also do it this way:

Create an Intent based on the Action instead of the class

```
public static final String ACTION = "com.example.android.receivers.NOTIFICATION_ALARM";

private void createNotification(String pDate, String pTime) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
}
```

Then you can handle multiple actions in your receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context pContext, Intent pIntent){
        if (pIntent.getAction().equals(ACTION)){
            // Here your handle code
        }
}
```

But then, you will have to declare your receiver in the manifest this way:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.android.receivers">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.android.receivers.NOTIFICATION_ALARM" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You can use both ways.