# Time Sensitive Notifications

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a simple app that sends notifications to the device but only on a specific day/time.  I have been able to get the notification part to work but cant seem to get the day & time problem solved.  Any ideas?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class NotificationsActivity extends Activity {
    int notificationID = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        displayNotification();
    }

    protected void displayNotification()
    {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
        i.putExtra("notificationID", notificationID);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

        Notification notif = new Notification(
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, 
            "Reminder: Meeting starts in 5 minutes",
            System.currentTimeMillis());


        CharSequence from = "System Alarm";
        CharSequence message = "Meeting with customer at 3pm...";

        notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, pendingIntent);


        notif.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500};
        nm.notify(notificationID, notif);        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule these events. Then, from the callbacks, you show the notifications.

See for example [Creating a Notification at a particular time through Alarm Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964349/creating-a-notification-at-a-particular-time-through-alarm-manager)

Be careful, as AlarManager will be cleared when the device reboots (you may need to re-register then on boot completed if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

See this link [Notification in Android Using AlarmManager, BoradCastReceiver & Services](http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.in/2012/09/notification-in-android-using.html)

It may be help you.